# Add prefix of root folder to all files in directory/subdirectories

Tags: file-rename, batch-rename

So I have a bunch of directories that are kind of like this (but with more files):

```
1-0
    file1
    file2
    folder
        file 3
1-1
    file1
    file2
    folder
        file 3
etc.
```

And as the question asks I want to prefix the 1-0, 1-1 to all the "files" in the directories and subdirectories of the root folder being the 1-0 etc. Like follows:

```
1-0
    1-0file1
    1-0file2
    folder
        1-0file 3
1-1
    1-1file1
    1-1file2
    folder
        1-1file 3
etc.
```

I've tried a few cmd/batch solutions from other questions and ReNamer but I couldn't find anything that quite did what I wanted. Pretty inexperienced with this kind of stuff so I could have missed something for sure.
ReNamer I can do it but I have to do each directory individually and I have a fair few that I am trying to rename so it's a bit impractical.

Comment: Hi Ross! Welcome :) Please could you share the code/commands that you have tried so far? Please do this by editing your question so that it's as visible as possible.

Comment: @tjheslin1 there wouldn't be much point in me providing some of the previous commands I had tried as they didn't really relate and I didn't understand how they worked. The answer provided by Ralf was exactly what I was looking for too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would find this in general a quite terrible idea to do... I cannot imagine a situation where on the long term this may really has been a good idea. One of the reasons is that it just duplicates structural information of the location in the filename itself. Why ?...

On a linux shell there are certainly various ways to accomplish this. Here is a one liner:

```
find . -type f -name "*" | xargs -n 1 -I {} sh -c 'file_full={}; file_bare=${file_full#./}; file=${file_bare##*/} prefix=${file_bare%%/*}; dir=${file_bare%/*}; echo mv ${file_full} ./${dir}/${prefix}${file}'
```

Note, there is an `echo` in the final output. Remove the `echo` only if you are really happy with the solution and want this to be executed.

Comment: Tldr I'm using some other programs (not developed by me) that do similar functions and I'm comparing results between them, and for that I need to compile the data. But how the results are exported from one of them is a bit yucky and I have no way to determine which root folder (1-0, 1-1, etc.) the file is from, hence if I labelled each file with the root folders name I can easily determine that. Not sure if that makes any sense but I didn't see another way to do it. This is only very prototype like work so it's not likely I'll redo this very much.

I will try your solution soon, thankyou!

Comment: This was exactly what I wanted as well! Thankyou.